# Php foreach outside loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

> I want to use at outside the loop my new array.
>   how i can do it?

```
$new = array();
foreach ($array as $data) {

    $url   = $data["result"]["url"];
    $name  = $data["result"]["name"];

    $new = array(
        $name => $url
    );
}
print_r($new);
```

Comment: instead of `$new = array(
        $name => $url
    );` make it `$new[$name] = $url;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
 $new = array(
    $name => $url
 );
```

edit it to

```
$new[$name] = $url;
```

so it will be at the end like this

```
$new = array();
foreach ($array as $data) {

    $url   = $data["result"]["url"];
    $name  = $data["result"]["name"];

    $new[$name] = $url;
}
print_r($new);
```